# How to set color of border and icon in outlined materialUI input?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to materialUI. This is how I'm using a simple input field which is outlined and has an icon. But as my background is dark, I need the color of the icon, the border and the text in a lighter color, e.g. grey.

What is the materialUI way to do this?

```
import Input from '@material-ui/core/OutlinedInput'
import InputAdornment from '@material-ui/core/InputAdornment'
import AccountCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle'

<Input
    name='username'
    type='text'
    placeholder='Username'
    startAdornment={
      <InputAdornment position='start'>
        <AccountCircle />
      </InputAdornment>
    }
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could achieve this is with the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/OutlinedInput";
import InputAdornment from "@material-ui/core/InputAdornment";
import AccountCircle from "@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: theme.spacing(4),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.black
  },
  input: {
    color: theme.palette.common.white,

    "&:hover $notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: theme.palette.grey[400]
    },
    "&$focused $notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: theme.palette.grey[400]
    },
  },
  notchedOutline: {
    borderColor: theme.palette.grey[400]
  },
  focused: {},
  adornedStart: {
    color: theme.palette.grey[400]
  }
}));

export default function Demo() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Input
        classes={{
          root: classes.input,
          notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
          focused: classes.focused,
          adornedStart: classes.adornedStart
        }}
        name="username"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Username"
        startAdornment={
          <InputAdornment position="start">
            <AccountCircle />
          </InputAdornment>
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-fermat-w6hcp?file=/src/Demo.js)

In my example I've used Material UI's own styling solution. But there are also a lot of other ways to solve this. You could also use [styled components](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#styled-components-api) for example.

Material UI has a great documentation. You can read a lot about styling solutions on [this page](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/). You could also [change the default theme](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/) which changes the styles for all input fields. Or you could use the [dark version](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/#dark-mode) of the Material UI theme which is already built in.

Comment: Looks great. I will have to go deeper on this. How do I handle the `hover` for the input in your example? It shouldn't be black.