# How to set Material UI OutlinedInput Placeholder color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have tried changing the placeholder color of the MaterialUI placeholder color but to no success.
Here is what I have tried so far

```
 const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
        emailField: {
            width: 265,
            height: 13,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            '&::placholder': { //This is meant to change the place holder color to green
                color: 'green'
            }
        }
    }));
    const classes = useStyles(theme);


    .....

    // Here is where I am trying to apply the styled class to the input element but to
    //No Success

     <OutlinedInput
                placeholder="name@email.com"
                inputProps={{
                    className: classes.emailField
                }}
            />
```

Any suggestion(s) to getting this right will be really appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set color of border and icon in outlined materialUI input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61556059/how-to-set-color-of-border-and-icon-in-outlined-materialui-input)

Comment: @ShahrzadGh No it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

This should be work ,Try this

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  customTextField: {
    "& input::placeholder": {
      color: "green"
    },
});
```

**Update**

You can make a custom style

```
const useOutlinedInputStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "green"
    },
    "&.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "green"
    }
  }
});
```

```
  const outlinedInputStyles = useOutlinedInputStyles();
```

import outlinedInput

```
import OutlinedInput from "@material-ui/core/OutlinedInput";
```

```
      <OutlinedInput
          classes={outlinedInputStyles}
          id="id"
          labelWidth={40}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Targeting the `::placeholder` pseudo selector will not work because the placeholder that you see in Material-UI Input components is actually the label of that input, which is animated on focus by javascript

**So in order to change the placeholder color target the `.MuiFormLabel-root` class in your CSS file then change the color** and make sure to import the CSS file into your component

```
.MuiFormLabel-root {
  color: green !important;
}
```

check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-first-zger5?file=/src/App.js) codesandbox to play around

Answer (score -1):

Please fix your spell in style.
From "&::placholder" to "&:placeholder".